# Fourier transform of $\theta(x-L)f(x)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Is there anything special one can say about the fourier transform

$$\hat g(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx e^{i x y} g(x)$$

of the function

$$g(x)=\theta(x-L)f(x)$$

where $L>0$, $\theta(x-L)$ is the Heaviside step function and $f(x)$ is some well behaved test function?

Comment: The Fourier transform of $sign(x)$ is $pv(\frac{c}{ y})$, of $\theta(x)$ it is $\pi\delta(y)+pv(\frac{c}{ y})$ of $\theta(x-L)$ it is $e^{-iyL} (\pi\delta(y)+
 pv(\frac{c}{ y-L}))= \pi\delta(y)+e^{-iyL} 
 pv(\frac{c}{ y-L})$ of $\theta(x-L)f(x)$ it is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\hat{f}\ast (\pi\delta(y)+e^{-iyL} 
 pv(\frac{c}{ y-L}))$

Comment: @reuns very interesting, you should post this as an answer and I will accept!